# Extract image with Discord Bot

Tags: python, discord, bots

I have written the following code, but it does not work:

```
from discord.ext import commands
import discord
import uuid
import requests
import shutil

#intents = discord.Intents.default()
#intents.message_content = True
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='.')

def send_discord_message():
    url = "https://discord.com/api/v9/channels/1095975130758393868/messages"
    payload = {
        'content': "/generate description:world"
    }
    header = {
        'authorization': 'mytoken'
    }
    requests.post(url, data=payload, headers=header)


@client.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready")


@client.command()
async def save(ctx):
    try:
        url = ctx.message.attachments[0].url
    except IndexError:
        print("Error: No attachments")
        await ctx.send("No attachments detected!")
    else:
        if url[0:26] == "https://cdn.discordapp.com":
            r = requests.get(url, stream=True)
            imageName = str(uuid.uuid4()) + '.jpg'
            with open(imageName, 'wb') as out_file:
                print('Saving image: ' + imageName)
                shutil.copyfileobj(r.raw, out_file)
        else:
            print("Link is not valid")

client.run('Y2MzI5MzQ0NDE2Nw.GRfQle.Cf9gubsAH5AnPcRVibGBxfatL26IbnOU')
```

As soon as a message is written in the channel, the bot should check it for an image and download it.

When I start the program, the bot is online, but it does not respond to the messages.

Comment: You missed to specify `intents`. It must at least have the privilege to read channels

Comment: I have an older version of discord.py. In this version intents does not have to be specified.

Comment: Mate you need to remove your discord token from the snippet. Then immediately go to `discord.dev` and reset your token.

Comment: Regarding your actual question, maybe try replace `r.raw` with `r.content`?

Comment: Just asking, why not upgrade your `discord.py` to a newer version. That could help avoid bugs concerning the interaction between the older version of `discord.py` and the Discord API. Concerning OP, I don't see anything wrong on the `discord.py` side. It might be something, like Anony Mous suggested, in the way you save the image.